# Web-scraping: unable to extract the required text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the novel description from this url https://www.wuxiaworld.co/Horizon-Bright-Moon-Sabre/

Howevery, when I try this code:

```
html=requests.get(site)
html.encoding = html.apparent_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,"html.parser")
summary = soup.find(id ='intro').get_text()
print (summary)
```

I get:

> Description
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
site = "https://www.wuxiaworld.co/Horizon-Bright-Moon-Sabre/"
html = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content)
summary = soup.find(id ='intro')
print(summary.text)
```

This prints out:

> Description Fu Hongxue was a cripple, born with a lame leg and subject
>   to epileptic seizures. He was also one of the most powerful, legendary
>   figures of the martial arts world, with a dull black saber that was
>   second to none. His fame made him a frequent target of challengers,
>   but whenever his saber left its sheath, only corpses would remain in
>   its wake. One day, however, F...

Comment: thanks it works, but why didn't the previous code work?

Comment: I suspect because you changed the HTML encoding and changed the default parser. This seems to remove the description text you wanted to scrape.

Comment: If your matter is solved please mark the answer as accepted so that others can see that your question has been answered.